# What are these groups known as, and are their orders multiplicative functions?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

This question has arisen in my work, and I imagine it is fairly standard to those more algebraic than myself.

Suppose for simplicity that $n$ is odd and squarefree, let $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$ be the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and let $H\leq \mathbb Z_n^{\times}$ be a subgroup.

Associated with each divisor $d|n$, one can form a new subgroup, say $H_d$, defined by

$$H_d=\{h\in H: h\equiv 1 \pmod d\}.$$

In other words, the elements of $H_d$ are precisely those that are trivial on $\mathbb{Z}_d^{\times}$.

Firstly, I would like to ask: do these subgroups have a name/standard interpretation in algebraic terms?

Secondly, having tried a few cases (for example when $H$ is a Boolean subgroup) it seems that the $|H_d|$ might be multiplicative functions, that is

$$|H_{de}|=|H_d||H_e|,$$

so I would like to ask if this a known result?

Comment: Have you checked some examples for certain $n$ and $d$? If $d,e$ are divisors of $n$, the product $de$ need not be a divisor of $n$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I don't know any special name. The  $|H_d|$ are ire indeed multiplicative in a special sense:   if $d, e$ are *coprime*, the $H_{de}^\times\simeq H_d^\times \times H_e^\times$ by the *Chinese remainder theorem*, whence theformula for  coprime $d$ and $e$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde and Bernard, Thank you! I have been inaccurate in specifying which divisors I'm interested in - actually I'm only interested in divisors whose product divides $n$, and I've only checked this in such cases. Seems to be true for low degree $p$-subgroups. Also, indeed, the squarefree assumption is there to avoid non-coprime divisors.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for every positive integer $n$, every positive divisor $d$ of $n$, and every subgroup $H\subset(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$, we have $H_d=H\cap\ker\varphi_d=\ker\varphi_d|_H$, where $\varphi_d$ is the natural group homomorphism
$$\varphi_d:\ (\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})^{\times}\ \longrightarrow\ (\Bbb{Z}/d\Bbb{Z})^{\times}.$$
I don't know of any standard name for such a subgroup.

It is easy to see that the identity $|H_{de}|=|H_d||H_e|$ cannot hold in general, because $H_{de}\subset H_d$.